# Adding validation for list of elements in Go

Tags: validation, go

I am new to golang

I have created a REST service using golang. I am trying to add validaiton and i am stuck in it.

I have two structs like

```
type Item struct {
    ProductId string `json:"prodId"`
    SkuId   string `json:"skuId"`
    Qty     string `json:"qty"`
}

type AddItemsRequest struct {
    Items []Item `json:"items" validate:"required"`
}
```

I am trying to validate `AddItemsRequest`

I added below code for handling this

```
func (r * Item) Validate() error {
    return types.ErrorMap{
        "prodId": validation.Validate(&r.ProductId, validation.Required, validation.Length(1, 255)),
        "skuId":   validation.Validate(&r.SkuId, validation.Required, validation.Length(1, 255)),
        "qty":     validation.Validate(&r.Qty, validation.Required, validation.Length(1, 255)),
    }
}

func (r AddItemsRequest) Validate() error {
    return validation.ValidateStruct(&r,
        validation.Field(&r.Items, validation.Each(is.Alpha))) // Instead of Alpha how to validate each items with my Items rule
}
```

But I am not bale to valdiate. How can i add validation code, so that items in request is not empty or blank and only String?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Can you show a full MVCE? a go play link?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what validation is, but I can use 'github.com/go-playground/validator' to solve this problem.

```golang
func main() {
   v := validator.New()
   v.RegisterValidation("mySlice", func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
      sli, ok := fl.Field().Interface().([]string)
      if !ok {
         return false
      }
      for i := range sli {
         if len(sli[i]) < 5 {
            return false
         }
      }
      return true
   }, false)

   sli := []string{"hello world", "hi", "congratulation"}
   err := v.Var(sli, "mySlice")
   if err != nil {
      panic("check error: " + err.Error())
   }
   print("ok")
}
```